# How to get quicksort depth?

Tags: c, algorithm, quicksort

> Alex has some pillars of different heights. He is trying to arrange the pillars in descending order according to their heights. Recently he has learned Divide & Conquer (D&C) algorithm strategy. There is a sorting algorithm in Divide & Conquer whose special case is, f(n) = O(n^2). So, now you have to help Alex to sort the pillars with that particular D&C algorithm. Finally, you need to display k, the number of times the division will be required for sorting, and also display the heights in descending order.

> Input: At the first line, you have to take the number of pillars, N (1<=N<=100), then, in the second line, you have to take N integer numbers indicating the heights of the pillars.

> Output: You need to display k and the height of the pillars in descending order

```
Sample Input:
6

6 3 8 11 2 77

Sample Output:
3
77 11 8 6 3 2
```

---

Code from [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1BSaX.png):

```
#include<stdio.h>
int k=0;
void swap(int *a, int *b)
{
    int t=*a;
    *a=*b;
    *b=t;
}

int partition(int a[], int low, int high)
{
    int pivot=a[high];
    int i=(low-1);

    for(int j-low;j<high; j++)
    {
        if(a[j]>=pivot){
            i++;
            swap(&a[i],&a[j]);
        }
    }

    swap(&a[i+1],&a[high]);
    return (i+1);
}

void quicksort(int a[], int low, int high)
{
    if(low<high)
    {
        int pi-partition(a,low,high);
 
        quicksort(a,low,pi-1);
        quicksort (a,pi+1,high);
        k++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: Yeah. I tried. But I'm not getting the division number

Comment: The question is hard to understand, but it seems like it's asking you to count the number of calls to `partition`. If so, you can do that either with a global variable, or by plumbing through a pointer argument, or by changing the return types of the functions to include a count. The global variable approach is by far the simplest.

Comment: I tried with a global variable. some times it gives and+1 or sometimes ans-1.

Comment: How do you divide(partition) the pillars?